# Angular 2 - Can we bind JSON object directly from typescript file to html input value?

Tags: angular

I have the following code in my .ts file.

```
yourInfoData: IYourInfoData; //IYourInfoData is my constructor

getYourInfoData() {
  $this = this;
  $this.yourInfoData = yourInfoDataResponse; //yourInfoDataResponseis my response from service.
}
```

yourInfoDataResponsestructure is as follows:

```
yourInfoDataResponse{
  "firstName" : "Xyz",
  "lastName" : "Abc"
}
```

Can I access this.yourInfoData directly to bind with html input value as below :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourInfoData.firstName">
```

Doing so, I am getting an error

> Cannot find firstName of undefined.

Can someone point to me what am I missing here. Or, is there other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

If you get the JSON from a service it's probably async and arrives with a delay

When Angular tries to resolve the template bindings while the data is not available it fails.

You can use the safe-navigation (Elvis) operator to avoid the error

```
<!-- doesn't work 
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourInfoData?.firstName">
-->
```

See this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7697

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="yourInfoData?.firstName"
                   (ngModelChange)="yourInfoData.firstName=$event">
```

or if it can happen that the model changes before `yourInfoData` is set

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="yourInfoData?.firstName"
                   (ngModelChange)="yourInfoData ? yourInfoData.firstName=$event : null">
```

this would also work

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="yourInfoData" [(ngModel)]="yourInfoData.firstName">
```

but it wouldn't display the input unless `yourInfoData` is set.

Comment: Tried that too. Received this error in the console :

zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 25 in [yourInfoData?.fisrtName=$event] in YourInfoComponent@6:47 ("
    <md-card-content>
        <p>
            <md-input placeholder="First name" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="yourInfoData?.fisrtName"></md-input>
        </p>
        <p> 
"): YourInfoComponent@6:47 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Comment: You are right. Sorry I didn't pay attention. I updated my answer.

Comment: Works like magic. Thanks a lot Günter Zöchbauer. Solves my issue.